Ansible: gather_subset - unable to get information on any fact with an underscore in the name
Trying to generate a report that shows the mount.device, mount.mount and mount.size_total information. Playbook runs without errors as long as I do not include anything that contains an underscore. For instance, if I remove the size_total - works.  Add in size_total or inode_total or block_size it makes with the following error.
failed | msg: The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'size_total'

Ran the playbook without the size_total - playbook works.  Ran playbook with size_total - playbook fails.  Ran the playbook with block_used - fails.
What I expect with size_total added:
localhost,/dev/mapper/sda1,/boot,533377024

What I get
failed | msg: The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'size_total'

---

  - name: make a csv file
    hosts: g3prdapp
    gather_facts: false

    tasks:

      - ansible.builtin.setup:
          gather_subset:
            - all_ipv4_addresses
            - mounts
            - user_id

      - debug:
          var: ansible_mounts

      - debug:
          var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses

      - debug:
          var: ansible_user_id

      - copy:
          dest: mount_output.csv
          content: |
            hostname,filesystem,mountpoint,size_total
            {% for hostname in ansible_play_hosts %}
            {% for mount in hostvars[hostname]['ansible_mounts'] %}
            {{ hostname }},{{ mount.device }},{{ mount.mount }},{{ mount.size_total }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
#        run_once: true
        delegate_to: localhost


"Playbook runs without errors", which playbook? Here is no. Therefore the question, can you provide your playbook code? As well. the output generated from a successful run and the output from a failing run together with the error messages? Because of "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute ...", can you provide the debug output of your variables too?

Welcome to StackOverFlow.  Please read [ask] a good question. Always provide a [mcve] of the code you are using as well as the output of that code.

Sorry about forgetting the details of the playbook...

How about the playbook output, variables content, debug messages, etc.?

A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "mounts"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: |
        hostname,filesystem,mountpoint,size_total
        {% for hostname in ansible_play_hosts %}
        {% for mount in hostvars[hostname]['ansible_mounts'] %}
        {{ hostname }},{{ mount.device }},{{ mount.mount }},{{ mount.size_total }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

results into an output of
TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    hostname,filesystem,mountpoint,size_total
    localhost,/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root,/,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/sda2,/boot,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/sda1,/boot/efi,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_home,/home,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_opt,/opt,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_var,/var,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_log,/var/log,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_audit,/var/log/audit,1234567890
    localhost,/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_tmp,/tmp,1234567890

on

RHEL 7.9, Python 2.7.5, Ansible 2.9.27 or Ansible 2.11
RHEL 8.9, Python 3.6.8, Ansible 2.14.9
RHEL 9.3, Python 3.9.18, Ansible 2.14.9
localhost
Remote Managed Nodes

Based on the currently given information your problem is not reproducible.

interesting - can i ask which version of python you are running.

Everything just out-of-box, plain OS, so Python 3.6.8 and Python 3.9.18.

we are not running version 3.  I ran your suggestion and it still failed.
